# how to trigger a outlook macro for new mails from shared inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

This code works perfectly for a normal inbox, but how to change the code to trigger an acknowledgement (only for new mails, need to exclude Re and Forward mails the comes to the inbox folder) from a shared mailbox (xxx@mail.com).folder(inbox)

**how to modify this code to trigger from a specific shared mailbox "Inbox"**

```
Public WithEvents xlItems As Outlook.Items
        Private Sub Application_Startup()
        Set xlItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
        End Sub
```

**Full Code:**

```
Public WithEvents xlItems As Outlook.Items
    Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set xlItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
    End Sub
    Private Sub xlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal objItem As Object)
    Dim xlReply As MailItem
    Dim xStr As String
    If objItem.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub
    Set xlReply = objItem.Reply
    With xlReply
         xStr = "<p>" & "Hi Team, Acknowledging that we have received the Job. Thank you!" & "</p>"
         .HTMLBody = xStr & .HTMLBody
         .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

**I tried Modifying the code but it did not work**

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items
  Dim objNS As NameSpace
  Set objNS = Application.Session
  ' instantiate objects declared WithEvents
  Set olInboxItems = objNS.Folders("xxxxxxxx@gmail.com").Folders("Inbox").Items
  Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim xlReply As MailItem
Dim xStr As String
If objItem.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub
Set xlReply = objItem.Reply
With xlReply
     xStr = "<p>" & "Hi Team, Acknowledging that we have received the Job. Thank you!" & "</p>"
     .HTMLBody = xStr & .HTMLBody
     .Send
End Sub
```

Comment: When posting describe any problems you see. In the modified code you should have an error on `If objItem.Class <> olMail Then` because `objItem` does not exist. The modified code is missing `Private Sub Application_Startup()`. Copy code directy from your editor.

Comment: I tried, But I could not figure the code Niton, Please can you please fix this.  The code mentioned in **Full Code** works fine. I'm facing a problem when I including the look from the shared folder under modified

Comment: Also if I include 'Private Sub Application_Startup()' it triggers acknowledge mail for a reply and forward mail as well. how to restrict those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be more robust than checking for "Re: " and "Fw: " in the subject.

In ThisOutlookSession

```
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Public WithEvents olItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    
    Set olItems = Session.Folders("xxxx@xxx.com").Folders("Inbox").Items
    
End Sub

Private Sub olItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim olReply As MailItem
 
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        
        If Len(Item.ConversationIndex) > 44 Then
            Exit Sub
        
        Else
        
            Set olReply = Item.reply
    
            With olReply
                .Body = "Reply to first email."
                .Display
            End With
        
        End If
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate your help Niton, Thank you. This code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the code myself finally. But it sends out mail for all the emails including (RE and FWD)

```
Public WithEvents olItems As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
' default local Inbox
Set olItems = objNS.Folders("xxxx@xxx.com").Folders("Inbox").Items

End Sub
Private Sub olItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim olReply As MailItem
 
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
       Set olReply = Item.Reply
    Else
       Exit Sub
    End If
 
    With olReply
         'Type Your Own Auto Reply
         'Change "John Smith" to Your Own Name
         .Body = "This is a test auto reply." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "-------Original Message-------" & vbCrLf & "From: " & Item.Sender & "[mailto: " & Item.SenderEmailAddress & "]" & vbCrLf & "Sent: " & Item.ReceivedTime & vbCrLf & "To: YourName" & vbCrLf & "Subject: " & Item.Subject & vbCrLf & Item.Body
         .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the primitive / intuitive version.
Subject must remain unchanged and be in English.

In ThisOutlookSession

```
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Public WithEvents olItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim objNS As namespace
    
    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olItems = objNS.Folders("xxxx@xxx.com").Folders("Inbox").Items
    
End Sub

Private Sub olItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim olReply As MailItem
 
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        
        If Left(UCase(Item.Subject), 4) = UCase("Re: ") Or _
           Left(UCase(Item.Subject), 4) = UCase("Fw: ") Then
            Exit Sub
        
        Else
        
            Set olReply = Item.reply
    
            With olReply
                .Body = "Reply to first email."
                .Display
            End With
        
        End If
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```